# Using IF AND/OR (ISNUMBER(SEARCH formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for a way to combine the three formulas below:

- =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*anonymous*",H2)),"Anonymous","Normal")
- =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*~?*",H2)),"Anonymous","Normal")
- =IF(H2="","Anonymous","Normal")

So if the text (multiply words) in H2 contains "?" or "anonymous" or is empty it should return "Anonymous". Otherwise it should return "Normal". All formulas work fine separately but I'm stuck on how to combine them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array in the SEARCH: `{"~?","Anonymous}`

Then it is just a matter of using `OR` strategically to check:

```
=IF(OR(H2="",OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"~?","anonymous"},H2)))),"Anonymous","Normal")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. However, it gives me the following error: "We found a problem with this formal. Try clicking Insert Function on the Formulas tab to fix it, or click Help for more info on common formula problems.". I am new to partly array formulas so I might be doing something wrong when entering the formula.

Comment: @Gauloisses do you use `;` instead of `,` as the delimiter?  as you can see, it works for me.  I did not photoshop the picture. It is entered normally, just like a normal formula.

Comment: I haven't changed anything. Just copied the formula (into Excel 2013 version) and confirmed with Enter (as normal formula). Also tried in a new empty Excel file but gives me the same error. Also when I don't copy but write the formula myself.

Comment: does it highlight anything when you hit ok?  again, I have no idea as it works for me as is.  I have copied and pasted the formula above twice without issue into my workbook.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't highlight so no idea why it works for you but not for me. However, I found another solution: =IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*anonymous*",H2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*~?*",H2)),H2=""),"Anonymous","Normal")

Thanks for your help!